# Installing/applying root CA certificate automatically

Tags: ssl, openssl

Is there a way to automatically install/apply a root CA to clients? So that they won't get any not trusted certificate warning when visiting a local website?

I have a local DNS configured and added to it to my router. Can I, if possible, install the root CA in the router and that would affect the connected clients as well?

Comment: "Is there a way to automatically install/apply a root CA to clients?" - Only if their operating system trusts the Root Authority.  Since this is marked OpenSSL I can only assume your talking about self-signed CA certificates.  As an Administrator of a system you can create a operating system image, which already trusts the self-signed CA if you want.

Comment: Yes it is self-signed. So the only way is to only install or get it pre-installed on the system?

Comment: If you don't want the user of the system to install it, yes, installing it for them is the only way for it the browser to automatically trust it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically install/apply a root CA to clients?

Yes, but it depends on the client. You can, for example, automatically (i.e. without end-user confirmation) install root CA certificates on Microsoft Windows machines in your domain with a group policy, but these certificates won't be honored by Firefox which uses its own certificate store.

Encryption protocols rely on PKI (certificates) to establish trust. The trust is defined by **the owner** of the client (an operating system or a browser).

Some clients that are aimed at corporate environments allow defining trust by the owner (**a company**) without notifying end-users.

> I have a local DNS configured and added to it to my router.

The mechanisms for the above are separate from DNS.

SSL/TLS and other protocols utilising PKI are actually meant to prevent the DNS server-owners from abusing their power by surreptitiously redirecting users' traffic.

> Can I, if possible, install the root CA in the router and that would affect the connected clients as well?

Fortunately you cannot. If you could, the whole PKI would provide no security.

Comment: Depends on what scenario?

Comment: To OS of the client. @John